# Change form output from Django Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form:

```
class InspectionReportForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InspectionReport
        fields = ('Date', 'Comment', 'Signature')
        labels = {"Date": "Date (YYYY-MM-DD)"}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(InspectionReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["Comment"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields["Date"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields["Signature"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Which stores a report, in addition to the date and who wrote it.

In the case of a "Pass" or "Fail" report. I want a generic comment in the report, so this would be auto-filled, which is why I have hidden this field. Date and Signature will be taken from the date of submission and the signature will be the logged in user. So mostly all auto-filled.

However I have a "Maybe" option which prompts the user for a comment and submits that instead of the generic ones.

My question is how do I change the comment value of the form from the HTML Template/Javascript stage of my project?

My current code is as follows:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <center><button type="button" id="pass">Pass</button> 
                        <button type="button" id="fail">Fail</button>
                        <button type="button" id="check" class="collapsible">Check</button>
                        <div class="content"> Comment: <input type="text" name ="comments">
                            <button id="submitCheck">Submit</button>
                        </div>
               </center>
```

The `Check` button is just a collapsible container that has an input box and a submit button for the "Maybe" option.

As far as Javascript I have nothing really because I can't directly change the field value from here. I've tried selecting the field with `{%for field in form%}` but had no luck

Comment: you can copy the contents of your `comments` input field to the `Comment` input field, which is a bit of a dirty trick I'd say. e.g. `$("input[name=comments]").on("change", function() {$("input[name=Comment]").val($(this).val());})`

Comment: Better would be to not make it a hidden input, and not to use `{{ form.as_p }}` but render the fields separately, e.g. `{{ form.Date.label_tag }}{{ form.Date }}` so that you can render the `{{ form.Comment }}` field directly inside your collapsible. And don't have to do anything in javascript.

Comment: @dirkgroten I like that idea, do you know how I would change the date and signature fields if they remain hidden? It would just take the current date and the logged in users username

Comment: why do you have them in your form anyway if they're hidden and don't contain any value? Remove them from you form and assign the values to the model in your view (as you probably do now). `report = form.save(commit=False); report.Date = ...; report.Signature = ...; report.save()`

Comment: Ah of course. Had a brain leak on that. Thanks for the help! If you put your first two comments into an answer I'd be happy to accept that as my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the "dirty trick" of copying the contents of your `comment` field into the hidden `Comment` field using javascript:

```
$("input[name=comments]").on("change", function(){
    $("input[name=Comment]").val($(this).val());
})
```

Or, what I believe is a better approach, don't use `{{ form.as_p }}` but render the fields separately so that you can render the `{{ form.Comment }}` field directly inside your collapsible. Then you don't have to do anything in javascript. You can render a field's label, the field itself and the field errors like this:

```
{{ form.Date.label_tag }}
{{ form.Date }}
{{ form.Date.errors }}
```